# Check a String matches a Regex

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use JavaScript to do some client-side validation to check whether a string matches the regex:

Whath is wrong in my js ..?

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/IRigIYpE43st5GKsGBRl?p=preview)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "30/12/2015";
    var patt = new RegExp("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to use a regular expression to achieve that. You can take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions. If you want to parse the date, some libraries could be useful (moment.js).

Comment: That's a date format, not a regular expression. You may need to do a bit of background reading on what a regular expression is.

Comment: i want just to test the string not the date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a regular expression. The easiest (but rather naive) solution would be:

```
var isDateCorrect = new Date(str).toString() !== "Invalid Date";
```

`new Date(str)` will try to parse the date and if it fails, it'll return the object that after calling `toString` on it produces a string `Invalid Date`, so you've got kind of a native date validation.

Answer (score 1):

Regex to just check the format of the input string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "11/12/2015";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDateFormat(str);
}

function testDateFormat(str) {
    return (str.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/)) ? true : false;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DD/MM/YYYY` is not a valid RegEx.  Use `\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d` instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "30/12/2015";
    var patt = new RegExp("\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d");
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```